# Removing Special Characters and bulk renaming

Tags: linux, bash, loops, shell, for-loop

I am trying to make a shell script to remove special characters, like {}()!,' etc. So far I have referenced a past question I asked here, however I get a strange error message:

```
-bash-3.2$ ./test2.sh
./test2.sh: line 7: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./test2.sh: line 10: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

#### test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *
do
        if [ -f "$file" ]; then
        newfile="`echo $file | tr -d '[{}(),\!]' | tr -d "\'" | sed 's/_-_/_/g'`"
        mv "$file" "$newfile"
        fi
done
```

Not sure where I am going wrong on this one, the files are named like:

```
Folder - 01
Folder 02!
Folder(03)
Folder Four_Three
```

The desired output would be

```
Folder 01
Folder 02
Folder 03
Folder Four Three
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *; do echo "mv $i ${i//[[:punct:]]/}"; done
```

Comment: This is the closest answer so far, it runs the script, appears to run, but when I run ls -la it doesn't show the changes as made.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a double-quote in the `if` test.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! However when I added it and re-ran it, it is still giving me the unexpected EOF error.

Comment: Worked for me in Cygwin bash.  However, the double-quotes surrounding the definition of `newfile` are superfluous and may be conflicting with the double-quotes around the string argument to the second `tr`. Try removing the outer double-quotes.

Comment: Its strange, it runs, but it doesn't fix any of the folders that are named Folder(03), Folder 02!, etc

Answer (score 0):

You are testing whether `$file` is a file, but you apparently want to rename directories (unless you have non-directory files named "Folder*"). Change your test to:

```
if [ -d "$file" ]; then
```